# Efficiently placing a cursor on a scene/group so that it appears on front of a Text string

Tags: java

I am creating javafx.Text objects (maintained in an instance of LinkedList) and placing them on javafx.Group (i.e: sourceGroup.getChildren().add(Text)). Each Text instance holds only one letter (not an entire word).

I have a click even that returns the x and y coordinates of the click. I want to drop a cursor to appear in front of the letter. This needs to be done in constant time, so I cant just iterate over my LinkedList and examine the Text x and y values.

There are certain restrictions on the libraries I can use. I can essentially only use javafx stuffs and java.util stuffs.

I was reading that HashMaps lookups essentially take place in constant time. My idea to drop the cursor is to:

1) While adding Text to the LinkedList instance, I want to update four hashMaps. One hashMap for the upper X value, one for the lower X value and the same for the Y values.

2) when it comes time to drop a cursor, i grab the x and y coordinates of the mouse click and perform a series of intersections (this part im not sure how to do yet) which should return the Text or subset of texts that fall between the X range and the Y range.

My Question:
Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? Am I being terribly inefficient with this idea?

Comment: Why not just use a [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html)?  Why all of the weird constraints?

Comment: @jewelsea it is a programming assignment to build a word processor. The constraints are there so that we have to micromanage all the small details.  I believe that the intent is to force the student modularize and handle a lot of small pieces (handle complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click listener to each text item, and, when the mouse is clicked on the text, reposition the cursor based upon the text bounds in parent.

[image: mares]

It's your homework, so you may or may not wish to look at the following code...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SillySong extends Application {
    private static final String lyrics =
            "Mares eat oats and does eat oats and little lambs eat ivy.  ";

    private static final int CURSOR_HEIGHT = 16;
    private static final int INSET = 2;

    private static final int N_LYRIC_REPEATS = 10;

    private Line cursor = new Line(INSET, INSET, INSET, INSET + CURSOR_HEIGHT);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FlowPane textPane = new FlowPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < N_LYRIC_REPEATS; i++) {
            lyrics.codePoints()
                    .mapToObj(this::createTextNode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(textPane::getChildren));
        }
        textPane.setPadding(new Insets(INSET));

        Pane layout = new Pane(textPane, cursor) {
            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();

                layoutInArea(textPane, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, new Insets(0), HPos.LEFT, VPos.TOP);
            }
        };

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(layout);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 200, 150));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Text createTextNode(int c) {
        Text text = new Text(new String(Character.toChars(c)));

        text.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            Bounds bounds = text.getBoundsInParent();

            cursor.setStartX(bounds.getMinX());
            cursor.setStartY(bounds.getMinY());
            cursor.setEndX(bounds.getMinX());
            cursor.setEndY(bounds.getMinY() + CURSOR_HEIGHT);
        });

        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This was just a basic sample, if you want to study something more full featured, look at the source of [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).

Truly, `new TextField()` is simpler :-)

---

So, what's really going on in the sample above?  Where did all your fancy hash tables for click support go?  How is JavaFX determining you clicked on a given text node?  Is it using some kind of tricky algorithm for [spatial indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) such as a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or a [kdtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)?

Nah, it is just doing a straight [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) of the scene graph tree and returning the first node it finds that intersects the click point, taking care to loop through children in reverse order so that the last added child to a parent group receives click processing priority over earlier children if the two children overlap.

For a parent node (Parent.java source):

```
@Deprecated
@Override protected void impl_pickNodeLocal(PickRay pickRay, PickResultChooser result) {

    double boundsDistance = impl_intersectsBounds(pickRay);

    if (!Double.isNaN(boundsDistance)) {
        for (int i = children.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            children.get(i).impl_pickNode(pickRay, result);
            if (result.isClosed()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (isPickOnBounds()) {
            result.offer(this, boundsDistance, PickResultChooser.computePoint(pickRay, boundsDistance));
        }
    }
}
```

For a leaf node (Node.java):

```
@Deprecated
protected void impl_pickNodeLocal(PickRay localPickRay, PickResultChooser result) {
    impl_intersects(localPickRay, result);
}
```

So you don't need to implement your own geometry processing and pick handling with a complicated supporting algorithm, as JavaFX already provides an appropriate structure (the scene graph) and is fully capable of processing click handling events for it.

---

*Addressing additional questions or concerns*

> I know that searching trees is fast and efficient, but it isn't constant time right?

Searching trees is not necessarily fast nor efficient.  Search speed depends upon the depth and width of the tree and whether the tree is ordered, allowing a binary search.  The scene graph is not a [binary search tree[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or a [b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or any other kind of tree that is optimized for search.  The hit testing algorithm that JavaFX uses, as can be seen above is a in-order traversal of the tree, which is [linear](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-running-time-for-an-inorder-traversal) in time: [O(n)](http://bigocheatsheet.com).

If you wanted, you could subclass parent, region, pane or group and implement your own search algorithm for picking by overriding functions such as `impl_pickNodeLocal`.  For example, if you constrain your field to a fixed width font, calculation of which letter a click will hit is trivial function that could be done in constant time via a simple mathematical equation and no additional data structures.

---

*Starting to get really off-topic aside*

But, even if you can do implement a custom hit processing algorithm, you need to consider whether you really should.  Obviously the default hit testing algorithm for JavaFX is sufficient for most applications and further optimizations of it for the general use case are currently deemed unnecessary.  If there existed some well-known golden algorithm or data structure that greatly improved its quality and there was sufficient demand for it, the hit-testing algorithm would have been further optimized already.  So it is probably best to use the default implementation unless you are experiencing performance issues and you have a specific use case (such as a mapping application), where an alternate algorithm or data structure (such as an [r-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)), can be used to effect a performance boost.  Even then, you would want to benchmark various approaches on different sizes and types of data sets to validate the performance on those data sets.

You can see the evidence of the optimization approach such as I described above in the multiply algorithm for BigIntegers from the JDK.  You might think the number multiplication is a constant time operation, but, its not for large numbers, because digits in the numbers are represented in different bytes and it is necessary to process all of the bytes to perform the multiplication.  There are various algorithms out there for processing the bytes for multiplication, but the choice of what is the "most efficient" one depends upon the properties of the numbers themselves (e.g. their size).  For smaller numbers, a straight loop for [long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) is the most efficient, for larger numbers, the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is used and for larger numbers again the [Toom-Cook algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) is used.  The thresholds for choosing just how large a number is required to switch to the different algorithm would have been chosen via analysis and benchmarking.  Also, the number is being multiplied with itself (it is being squared), a more efficient algorithm can be used to perform the square (so that is an example of a special edge case that is being specifically optimized for).

```
/**
 * Returns a BigInteger whose value is {@code (this * val)}.
 *
 * @implNote An implementation may offer better algorithmic
 * performance when {@code val == this}.
 *
 * @param  val value to be multiplied by this BigInteger.
 * @return {@code this * val}
 */
public BigInteger multiply(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0 || signum == 0)
        return ZERO;

    int xlen = mag.length;

    if (val == this && xlen > MULTIPLY_SQUARE_THRESHOLD) {
        return square();
    }

    int ylen = val.mag.length;

    if ((xlen < KARATSUBA_THRESHOLD) || (ylen < KARATSUBA_THRESHOLD)) {
        int resultSign = signum == val.signum ? 1 : -1;
        if (val.mag.length == 1) {
            return multiplyByInt(mag,val.mag[0], resultSign);
        }
        if (mag.length == 1) {
            return multiplyByInt(val.mag,mag[0], resultSign);
        }
        int[] result = multiplyToLen(mag, xlen,
                                     val.mag, ylen, null);
        result = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(result);
        return new BigInteger(result, resultSign);
    } else {
        if ((xlen < TOOM_COOK_THRESHOLD) && (ylen < TOOM_COOK_THRESHOLD)) {
            return multiplyKaratsuba(this, val);
        } else {
            return multiplyToomCook3(this, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Nah, it is just doing a straight depth first search of the scene graph tree and returning the first node it finds that intersects the click point, taking care to loop through children in reverse order so that the last added child to a parent group receives click processing priority over earlier children if the two children overlap."
I know that searching trees is fast and efficient, but it isn't constant time right? I can also sneak in a thank you here.